Nested itemize doesn't vanish
I'm working on a presentation and want the nested itemize to vanish after being visible together with the parent item, while the parent item stays visible/transparent. I can't seem to get it right.
Here's my code
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Critical Curve}
The Critical Curve
\begin{itemize}[<+|visible@+->]
    \item exclusively corresponds to \textbf{spherical} orbits,
    \alt<1>{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item then this subitem should be shown also, and not in the next step
    \end{itemize}
    }{ }
    \item is \textbf{closed},
     \alt<2>{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item then this subitem should be shown also, and not in the next step
    \end{itemize}
    }{ }
    \item and is a \textbf{single curve}.
     \alt<3>{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item then this subitem should be shown also, and not in the next step
    \end{itemize}
    }{ }
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

I just made an edit! should be sufficient

Can you clarify what you mean with "vanish": be invisible and still occupy space or be completely absent. Can you clarify what you mean with "parent item stays visible/transparent" should it be visible or should it be transparent? Can you manually make a mock-up which shows how the result should look like? Should the subitems be uncovered at the same time as the parent item? Or later?

or does vanish maybe mean covered, e.i. semi-transparent?

@absent: vanish means completely absent to me, sorry for not clarifying. "parent item stays visible/transparent" by this I meant semi-transparent. the subitems should be uncovered at the same time as the parent item.

You can use [<only@-.>] to show the child items only on the overlay together with their parent:
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Critical Curve}
The Critical Curve
\begin{itemize}[<uncover@+|only@+->]
    \item exclusively corresponds to \textbf{spherical} orbits,
    \begin{itemize}[<only@-.>]
        \item then this subitem should be shown also, and not in the next step
    \end{itemize}
    \item is \textbf{closed},
    \begin{itemize}[<only@-.>]
        \item then this subitem should be shown also, and not in the next step
    \end{itemize}
    \item and is a \textbf{single curve}.
    \begin{itemize}[<only@-.>]
        \item then this subitem should be shown also, and not in the next step
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



is there a possibility that e.g. in the screenshot you have given that the "single curve" item is not visible (nor its corresponding subitem?)

@Geigercounter \item<only@+> and is a \textbf{single curve}. or change it in \begin{itemize}[<uncover@+>] if this should be the case of all parent items.

<only@+> also deletes the parent items before, which I would still like to be visible

@Geigercounter So \begin{itemize}[<uncover@+|only@+->] for the top level itemisation?
